# How to send output plot from 'checkresiduals() function to a pdf file

Tags: r

I am wondering if there is a way to send the output plot from the checkresiduals() function to a pdf file.

I have the following command :-

```
checkresiduals(ts_regr_auto_new_objects[[1]], test = FALSE, plot = TRUE)
```

This generates a series of plots including ACF plot, residual density plot and the residual plot.

Will try and attach the image - for some reason its not doing it now but hopefully can reproduce the image again later.

The image is attached now :-

[image]

I can save the save the image as a pdf file from the RStudio console but I would like to be able to do so from code as this is a part of a larger application code.

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `checkresiduals`, but generally it should be possible to save PDF with `base R`:

```
# start PDF output
pdf(file = "plot.pdf", paper = "a4")

# some graphics
hist(rnorm(100))

# end of output, save file
dev.off()
```

So for your case probably this:

```
pdf(file = "plot.pdf", paper = "a4")
checkresiduals(ts_regr_auto_new_objects[[1]], test = FALSE, plot = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

See [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html)... Hope this helps.

Comment: Petr - One more thing. Is there a way to use a loop to print the charts as multiple pages for each iteration of the loop like this :- pdf(file = "plot.pdf", paper = "a4"); for (i in 1:2) {checkresiduals(ts_regr_auto_new_objects[[i]]}; dev.off - possibly with facility to enter a title for each iteration i.e for each page. Also, can we position the image such that its not centered vertically?

Comment: Hi @DeepakAgarwal, the PDF is written on multiple pages by default, but you can change it by setting `pdf(..., onefile = FALSE)`. After printing a plot you should be able to add some text by `title("some text")` or `mtext("some text")`. Page centering is default, you can disable it by setting `pdf(..., pagecentre = FALSE)`, but in that case i recommend to play with `width` and `height` parameters of `pdf()`... See [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html). Let me know if it works for you.